# Unity3D Ver 5 Re-Using Script but want Different Copies

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, assets

I'm really new to Unity and I have made some scripts in my Assets folder. I can attach them to objects fine and they work. But If i attach the same script to multiple objects, the game breaks and changes made to a script on one object impact the script on another object by the same name. Do i have to duplicate each script before applying them to different objects to prevent this from happening? Each object needs to have the same script, but the scripts need to be independent if that makes sense.

I've tried doing research of people with similar problems and the topic of inheritance comes up. But that means I'd still have to write a child class for each object. I want to just write it once then apply it to all objects, then be able to modify each script on each object with different properties

Thanks

EDIT: MORE SPECIFIC

My problem really has to do with an animation trigger not being triggered on an object. I have 2 objects, Terminator and LieutenantDan. Both of these models have animations and the animations are not working properly on LieutenantDan, though they are working fine on Terminator. Both Models have the same 3 scripts attached to them:

*BasicProperties.cs*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
// PURPOSE: Defines basic root properties for many object types
// ATTACHMENT: Many types of objects
public class BasicProperties : MonoBehaviour {
    public int objectType;
    public string animWalkTrigger;
    public int facingInversion;
    void Start()
    {
    }
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

*Champion Properties.cs*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
// ATTACHMENT: Game Play Objects
// this Class initializes custom properties of the champion that can be 
manipulated
// as the game progresses
public class ChampionProperties : MonoBehaviour {
    // whether this object can be selected or not
    public bool selectable;
    // whether the user has currently selected the champion or not.
    public bool selected;
    // whether the object is moveable
    public bool moveable;
    // if the object is moveable it has to have a movespeed.
    public float moveSpeed;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // the champion is selectable
        selectable = true;
        // on load the champion is not selected
        selected = false;
        // the champion is moveable
        moveable = true;
        // set the moveSpeed
        moveSpeed = 10f;
    }
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

*ChampionBasicActions.cs*

```
public class ChampionBasicActions : MonoBehaviour {
    public ChampionProperties championProperties;
    public BasicProperties basicProperties;
    static Animator anim;
    public Vector3 objPos;
    public Vector3 destPos;
    void Start () {
        basicProperties = this.GetComponent<BasicProperties>();
        championProperties = this.GetComponent<ChampionProperties>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        objPos = this.transform.position;
        destPos = Vector3.zero;
    }
    void Update () {
        if ( destPos != Vector3.zero )
        {
            anim.SetBool(basicProperties.animWalkTrigger, true);
            float fpsMoveSpeed = championProperties.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            float maintainY = transform.position.y;
            destPos.y = maintainY;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, destPos, fpsMoveSpeed);
            if ( Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, destPos) < 0.01 )
            {
                this.transform.position = destPos;
                destPos = Vector3.zero;
            } else {
                Vector3 direction = (destPos - transform.position).normalized;
                Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(basicProperties.facingInversion * direction);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 100f);
            }
        } else {
            anim.SetBool(basicProperties.animWalkTrigger, false);
        }
    }
}
```

For the Basic Properties script for each Model, in Inspector view i have defined 'AnimWalkTrigger' variable to mean 'isWalkingLtDan' for LieutenantDan and 'isWalkingTerm' for the Terminator.

Both models also start with an idle animation but have a walking animation, for each defined by a different boolean trigger. For LieutenantDan the boolean trigger to start / stop walking is 'isWalkingLtDan' and for the Terminator the walking boolean trigger is 'isWalkingTerm'

When I play the scene, both characters are in the Idle position as expected. I can click on the Terminator and move him around, and he walks as he moves as expected, then returns to the idle position as expected.

However, when it comes to LieutenantDan, I can click on him and move him around, but he never enters the walking animation, he just stays in idle. As the scene plays I get this error message in the console

```
Parameter 'isWalkingLtDan' does not exist
```

This is referring to

```
 anim.SetBool(basicProperties.animWalkTrigger, false);
```

calls in the ChampionBasicActions script attached to each object. In the BasicProperties script attached to each object, i have defined the variable animWalkTrigger in the Inspector View to be 'isWalkingTerm' on the Terminator and 'isWalkingLtDan' on Lieutenant Dan.

For the Terminator, there is a transition in the Animator from Idle to Walking and back to Idle, and the trigger is the parameter 'isWalkingTerm'. This appears to be set up correctly.

For LieutenantDan, there is the same transition between animations but the trigger is correctly set to 'isWalkingLtDan'.

So why in the hell am I getting this error message? If i deactivate the 3 scripts on Terminator that are shared with LieutenantDan, suddenly LieutenantDan works fine and walks as expected, and the error message in the console stops. What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Objects that reference the same script will get the same functionality.  Properties/fields can change some of the behaviour, provided that *you* wrote that into your scripts.  Objects don't have copies of scripts on them, they have *references* to scripts.  Changing the script changes it for every object that references it.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question. I was using the static keyword for the animator definition in ChampionBasicActions. This caused each instance of the object to refer to the SAME animator object instead of the one particular to that object. Changing the keyword to 'public' solved the problem.